# Azure Kubernetes Error when running "az aks get-credentials" command

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Azure Admins created a cluster for us.
On VM I installed `"az cli" and "kubectl"`.
With my account from Azure Portal I can see that Kubernetes Service and Resource Group to which it belongs.
From the level of that cluster in Azure Portal I can see that I have a role:

> "AKS Cluster Admin Operator"

I am logged on  VM with kubectl with my account. I need to config my kubectl to work with our cluster.
When I try to execute:

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group FRONT-AKS-NA2 --name front-aks
```

I am getting error:

> ForbiddenError: The client 'my_name@my_comp.COM' with object id
> '4ea46ad637c6' does not have authorization to perform action
> 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterUserCredential/action'
> over scope
> '/subscriptions/89e05d73-8862-4007-a700-0f895fc0f7ea/resourceGroups/FRONT-AKS-NA2/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/front-aks'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials.

Comment: Try with `az aks get-credentials --resource-group FRONT-AKS-NA2 --name front-aks --admin`

Comment: @Hackerman hey it works! Thanks!!!
can you let me know the difference if I should use kubectl command with Admin or regular ClusterUser role? what's the difference?

Comment: @Hackerman is it safe and enough to use this Admin instead of the default Cluster User role? Thank you for answer it really helped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I see the comment, and you already get the solution. So I just can explain the difference to you. Hope it will help you!

When you use the command `az aks get-credentials` without parameter `--admin`, it means the CLI command uses the [default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az_aks_get_credentials-optional-parameters): Cluster user. And when you use the cluster user, it just works if you integrate AKS with the AAD. But you said you just have the `AKS Cluster Admin Operator` role, so the appropriate parameter is `--admin`. You can get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/control-kubeconfig-access#available-cluster-roles-permissions).

And on my side, it's a little dangerous. If the AKS cluster is just for the test, there is no problem. But if it's for production, I recommend you integrate with the AAD, and then give the appropriate permissions to the user. Because the admin user means you have all the permissions, you know, it's not safe.

Comment: Thank you Charles this resolved the issue... this is our first AKS cluster so facing many different issues : )

Comment: @AndreyDonald My pleasure: )

Comment: After reading this answer I started wondering what's the difference between `az aks get-credentials` with and without `--admin` if the cluster is **not** AAD enabled. It turns out without AAD integration there is no difference between clusterUser and clusterAdmin role.

Answer (score 13):

In my case to refresh recently granted credentials helped this one:

```bash
az account set --subscription "your current subscription name"
```

It leds to re-login and fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, this saved me in some other environment!